# Delete certain values from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to delete the keys in my dictionary with the value of `1`, but the only way I know of is to manually input keys to delete which is inefficient. Any ideas?

I have a feeling I should use:

```
for key,value in mydict.items():
```

For example, if I had the dictionary

```
mydict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':1, 'e':1}
```

how would I delete the keys with a value of `1` so that I can print a dictionary purely of keys with values `> 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to filter the dictionary:

```
>>> mydict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':1, 'e':1}
>>> {k:v for k,v in mydict.items() if v != 1}
{'c': 3, 'b': 2}
>>>
```

Note that you should use `mydict.iteritems()` if you are on Python 2.x to avoid creating an unnecessary list.

Answer (score 1):

You could go though each of the items (the key value pair) in the dictionary to check the conflict and add value in new Dict.(here.. result) that not contain duplicate.

```
mydict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':1, 'e':1}
result = {}

for key,value in mydict.items():
    if value not in result.values():
        result[key] = value

print result
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a new dictionary with the items which has the value greater than 1 use [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) like below.

```
>>> mydict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':1, 'e':1}
>>> {key:value for key,value in mydict.items() if value > 1}
{'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```